# Solutions to $(x+y)f(x+y)=xf(x)+yf(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

If $x$ is a differentiable function of $t$ and if we define

$$ f(x)=\frac{x^\prime}{x} $$

then $f$ satisfies logarithmic-like properties

1. $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $f(x/y)=f(x)-f(y)$
3. $f(x^n)=nf(x)$

but $f$ also satisfies the non-logarithmic-like property

4. $(x+y)f(x+y)=xf(x)+yf(y)$

Are there any algebraic functions satisfying the functional equation $(4)$?

Note: It is fairly easy to show that $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: Any additive function divided by identity function will work.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Not sure I understand. If you mean something like $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ then $xf(x)+yf(y)=xyf(xy)$, not $(x+y)f(x+y)$.

Comment: An additive function is $g$ such that $g(x+y) = g(x)+g(y)$.  The only continuous ones are $g(x) = k x$, but there are exotic discontinuous (and non-measurable) solutions as well.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Regarding your previous proof that no such function would exist, what had been the error with it?

Comment: No error.  I assumed differentiability.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ahh, okay. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @orangeskid I was supposing $\mathbb{R}$ or even $\mathbb{Z}$. Both deleted answers noted correctly that constant functions are solutions. Perhaps I should have specified 'non-trivial' but those seem to be the only solutions, or at least the only differentiable solutions as noted by@RobertIsrael.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $g(x) = x f(x)$, the equation (4) says $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$, i.e. $g$ is additive.  See [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y)f(x+y)=xf(x)+yf(y) $ (4)

Let $y=x$ you get that $f(2x)=f(x) $

Let $y=2x$ you get $f(3x) = f(x) $

Let $y=nx$ you get $f(nx) = f(x) $

And we know that $f(x) = f(-x) $

$f(1)=f(2)=f(4)=f(5)....$

so f is constant function ?